# Changing constant memory content through non-const pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, constants

Let's say I declare this variable in C:

```
const char*** const strings;
```

Now if I try this:

```
printf("character is : %c \n",***strings);

**strings="hello";

printf("strings is %s \n", **strings);

printf("character is : %c \n",***strings);
```

Sometimes, I get the following output:

```
character is :
strings is hello
character is : h
```

However sometimes I get a segfault because (I'm assuming) of the instruction

```
**strings="hello";
```

I thought that you could write `char* str = "hello";` in C, making str point to a non modifiable string "hello".
Why does this not work in my case?
Can anyone explain why it does not give the same output evertime?

Comment: you might want to look up "undefined behavior"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write:

```
const char*** const strings;
```

You're asking the compiler to allocate a pointer to a pointer to a string.

It does exactly this and nothing more:

- it does not allocate the string or the pointer to the string.
- it does not initialize the value to anything in particular.

So when you use it by dereferencing, you're essentially reading from/writing to to a random piece of memory, and whether or not it crashes is random.

Writing this instead will work:

```
char* empty = "";
char** pointer = &empty;
char*** strings = &pointer;
```

Your comment indicates you're not quite familiar with how const works, so let me explain:

```
const char*** const strings;
```

isn't fully read only. It looks something like this:

```
(constant pointer) -> (pointer) -> (pointer) -> (constant char)
```

So you're allowed to modify the middle pointers (*strings and **strings).

If you want a fully read only pointer, write this:

```
const char const * string = "hello";
const char const * const * string_pointer = &string;
const char const * const * const * string_pointer_pointer = &string_pointer;
```

And you no longer can modify anything.

Comment: So basically the problem comes from the fact that the pointer `strings` is not initialized at the beginning? I am still confused about the fact that we can change a memory location that is supposed to be non modifiable. For example, if I set 
 `char * str="abc";`
 `char ** ptr=&str;`
 `const char*** const strings=&ptr;`
How is it possible that the `***strings` change?

Comment: if you are still confused after this answer, then you should study pointers a bit more